# overriding styles using selector angular 2

Tags: angular

I have made a button class with some default style, and use it any where using the selector tag  the default button has its own component with html  and css here is the code"

**button.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  template: `
<button class="button button1" (click)="click()">
        <span class="ladda-label"> {{title}} </span>
    </button>
`,
  styleUrls: ['./button.component.css'],
})

export class ButtonComponent {}
```

**button.component.css**

```
      button {
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 14px;
      margin: 4px 2px;
      -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
      transition-duration: 0.4s;
      cursor: pointer;
      height: 6%;
      width: 6%;
    }

    .button1 {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: black;
      border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
    }

    .button1:hover {
      background-color: #006400;
      color: white;
      border: 2px solid #006400;

    }
.button2 {
      background-color: #5CAF50;
      color: green;
      border: 2px solid #4CA550;
    }
```

and this is how i use the button:

```
<app-button></app-button>
```

by using it i can acess the button with default syle that is the class="button button1"

but how can apply a different style and tell the selector to not load the default style but use the *style* with **button2** that is also declared in the same css of **button** component ,  basically override the new style rather the default one so i have advantage of re-usability.
some thing like this:

```
<app-button class="button button2"></app-button>//i want some thing like this to load the style with this class not th default one
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Input decorator :

import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  template: `
<button [ngClass]="classList" (click)="click()">
        <span class="ladda-label"> {{title}} </span>
    </button>
`,
  styleUrls: ['./button.component.css'],
})

export class ButtonComponent {

   @Input("class-list") classList: string;

}
```

template :

```
<app-button [class-list]="'button button2'"></app-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually `ngClass` you should be using as below,

```
<button [ngClass]="['button','button1']" (click)="click()">
        <span class="ladda-label"> {{title}} </span>
</button>
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/aF6RbyxIlK6E1UaUD8ND?p=preview)